# Flex with overflow and bootstrap navbar bevahes differently in Firefox/Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, bootstrap-4

When I use Firefox to display the snippet below, the `div` with class `h-100` is assigned the full page height (`100vh`), and the height of the `nav` is then added so that a second scroll bar is produced.

What I want is that only the `div` with `overflow-y: auto` should have a scroll bar.

The strange thing about this is that the code seems to behave as I want in Chrome and Safari.

Is there a problem with my HTML/CSS, and how can I work around this difference in behaviors?

```css
.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="root">
  <div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-dark"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a></nav>
    <div class="h-100" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
      <div style="flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto">
        <div id="foo" style="height: 1200px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set overflow hidden to the parent div.

```css
.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

#foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="root">
  <div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand bg-dark"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a></nav>
    <div class="h-100" style="display: flex; overflow: hidden; flex-direction: row">
      <div style="flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto">
        <div id="foo" style="height: 1200px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, it's that easy!? Do you know what the reason for the difference is, though? Do the browsers handle overflows or heights differently?

Comment: I think yes, the browsers handles overflow differently, as per my knowledge safari and chrome assumes overflow: auto for parent. While in case of Firefox its overflow: visible, that's why it was scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Comment: Oh, but now the content of `foo` that is next to the bottom is pushed out of the page... the height of the `h-100` `div` is still bigger in firefox than in the other browsers. Any idea? I'll put that in another question otherwise.